# WPF Animation on scrollviewer children clipped by scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

Hey folks, I'm hoping I have a fairly simple problem that can be fixed easily as it seems like I'm just missing something basic from the WPF world. I have a scrollviewer wrapping a stackpanel which contains several images, these images have animations to increasing in size when the mouse passes over them. All works fine *without* the scrollviewer, now I've added the scrollviewer, the animation works but only inside the scrollviewer; the increasing size isn't being allowed to overlap the scrollviewer.

Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks,
Becky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way ScrollViewer works. Basically it always clips to bounds even if you set ClipToBounds="False" on it.

To make it work and continue using ScrollViewer you'll have to animate images on top of it, not inside.