# Why am I receiving touch manipulation delta translation values only on the Y axis for elements inside a scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, touch, wpf-controls, translation

I am trying to replicate the default Windows 10 behavior for touch-and-drag vs touch-hold-and-drag manipulations in WPF. Why this isn't already part of the framework in 2021, only MS overlords can tell us, but after searching the internet high and low, trying varios implementations, trying to shoehorn the UWP framework in my WPF app, etc., I decided to try and implement it myself.

To better illustrate what I am after and ensure we're on the same page, I've attached the following clips to demonstrate:

| Touch and immediately drag | Touch, hold, then drag |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| Directory content is scrolled | Touched folder is dragged |

I got to a point where it looks like my method will work, however ManipulationDelta event for elements which are placed inside a scroll viewer with **Panning mode** set to **VerticalOnly** only seem to provide values for `Translation.Y`, `Translation.X` being always 0. Obviously, my fingers won't move just perfectly vertically on the screen, so I would like to receive values for both axes.

In order to achieve this, I created a couple of custom controls, the first of which exposes the `ManipulationDelta` property which I can bind to so that I can provide the values to other controls. It also allows me to update the control's RenderTransform in the `ManipulationDeltaCallback` method so that the controls position on screen changes:

```cs
public class Manipulatable : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationDeltaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ManipulationDelta", typeof(ManipulationDelta), typeof(Manipulatable), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ManipulationDeltaCallback)));

    private TransformGroup _transformGroup;
    private TranslateTransform _translation;
    //private ScaleTransform scale;
    //private RotateTransform rotation;

    public Manipulatable()
    {
        _transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        _translation = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
        //scale = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
        //rotation = new RotateTransform(0);

        _transformGroup.Children.Add(_translation);
        //transformGroup.Children.Add(scale);
        //transformGroup.Children.Add(rotation);

        RenderTransform = _transformGroup;
    }

    public new ManipulationDelta ManipulationDelta
    {
        get => (ManipulationDelta)GetValue(ManipulationDeltaProperty);
        set => SetValue(ManipulationDeltaProperty, value);
    }

    private static void ManipulationDeltaCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var manipulationDelta = e.NewValue as ManipulationDelta;
        var manipulatable = d as Manipulatable;
        manipulatable._translation.X += manipulationDelta.Translation.X;
        manipulatable._translation.Y += manipulationDelta.Translation.Y;
    }
}
```

The second class exposes properties for all of the relevant touch manipulations events, again, so I can bind to them, as well as the touch and hold functionality which WPF is lacking for God knows what reason:

```cs
public class TouchAndHold : Manipulatable
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TouchedAndHeldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TouchedAndHeld", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TouchedAndHeldParamProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TouchedAndHeldParam", typeof(object), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationStartingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ManipulationStarting", typeof(RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationStartedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ManipulationStarted", typeof(RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationDeltaChangedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ManipulationDeltaChanged", typeof(RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationCompletedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ManipulationCompleted", typeof(RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>), typeof(TouchAndHold), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        private double length;
        private bool _overrideTouch;
        private bool _held;
        private DispatcherTimer _touchHoldTimer;

        public TouchAndHold()
        {
            IsManipulationEnabled = true;
            _touchHoldTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _touchHoldTimer.Tick += _touchHoldTimer_Tick;
            _touchHoldTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(5000000);
        }

        public RelayCommand TouchedAndHeld
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(TouchedAndHeldProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TouchedAndHeldProperty, value); }
        }

        public object TouchedAndHeldParam
        {
            get { return GetValue(TouchedAndHeldParamProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TouchedAndHeldParamProperty, value); }
        }

        public new RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs> ManipulationStarting
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>)GetValue(ManipulationStartingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ManipulationStartingProperty, value); }
        }

        public new RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs> ManipulationStarted
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>)GetValue(ManipulationStartedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ManipulationStartedProperty, value); }
        }

        public RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs> ManipulationDeltaChanged
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>)GetValue(ManipulationDeltaChangedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ManipulationDeltaChangedProperty, value); }
        }

        public new RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs> ManipulationCompleted
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand<TouchAndHoldEventArgs>)GetValue(ManipulationCompletedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ManipulationCompletedProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewTouchDown(TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            length = 0;
            _held = false;
            _overrideTouch = true;
            _touchHoldTimer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewTouchUp(TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !_overrideTouch || _held;
            _held = false;
            _overrideTouch = false;
            _touchHoldTimer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationStarting(ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !_overrideTouch || _held;
            ManipulationStarting?.Execute(new TouchAndHoldEventArgs(_overrideTouch, _held, e));
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !_overrideTouch || _held;
            ManipulationStarted?.Execute(new TouchAndHoldEventArgs(_overrideTouch, _held, e));
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_held)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                ManipulationDeltaChanged?.Execute(new TouchAndHoldEventArgs(_overrideTouch, _held, e));
                return;
            }

            length += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Length;
            if (length >= 10)
            {
                _overrideTouch = false;
                _touchHoldTimer.Stop();
                return;
            }

            e.Handled = !_overrideTouch || _held;
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !_overrideTouch || _held;
            ManipulationCompleted?.Execute(new TouchAndHoldEventArgs(_overrideTouch, _held, e));
        }

        private void _touchHoldTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _held = true;
            _overrideTouch = false;
            _touchHoldTimer.Stop();
            TouchedAndHeld?.Execute(TouchedAndHeldParam);
        }

        public class TouchAndHoldEventArgs
        {
            public TouchAndHoldEventArgs(bool isTouchOverriden, bool isHeld, ManipulationStartingEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                IsTouchOverriden = IsTouchOverriden;
                IsHeld = isHeld;
                ManipulationStartingEventArgs = eventArgs;
            }

            public TouchAndHoldEventArgs(bool isTouchOverriden, bool isHeld, ManipulationStartedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                IsTouchOverriden = isTouchOverriden;
                IsHeld = isHeld;
                ManipulationStartedEventArgs = eventArgs;
            }

            public TouchAndHoldEventArgs(bool isTouchOverriden, bool isHeld, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                IsTouchOverriden = isTouchOverriden;
                IsHeld = isHeld;
                ManipulationDeltaEventArgs = eventArgs;
            }

            public TouchAndHoldEventArgs(bool isTouchOverriden, bool isHeld, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                IsTouchOverriden = isTouchOverriden;
                IsHeld = isHeld;
                ManipulationCompletedEventArgs = eventArgs;
            }

            public bool IsTouchOverriden { get; }
            public bool IsHeld { get; }

            public ManipulationStartingEventArgs ManipulationStartingEventArgs { get; }
            public ManipulationStartedEventArgs ManipulationStartedEventArgs { get; }
            public ManipulationDeltaEventArgs ManipulationDeltaEventArgs { get; }
            public ManipulationCompletedEventArgs ManipulationCompletedEventArgs { get; }
        }
    }
```

The touch and hold functionality works by having a boolean which, when set to true, ensures that all manipulation events are set handled (`e.Handled = true`). This ensures that all touch events are ignored further down the line, so that, for example, the scrollviewer doesn't start scrolling.

When `OnPreviewTouchDown` is called, I set the boolean to true so that events don't propagate. I also start a timer for the touch and hold part. In the mean time, I monitor how far the finger moves on the screen. If it moves far enough, I assume the user wants to scroll, so I stop doing anything and let WPF handle everything as it wants. If the finger doesn't move farther than the set limit before the timer fires, I assume that this is actually a touch and hold event. At this point I perform the following actions:

- Execute the `TouchedAndHeld` command to let whoever is interested know that this event occurred, passing along the relevant information;
- Start monitoring the for manipulation events and execute the `ManipulationDeltaChanged` command, again, to let whoever binds to this command know that manipulation events have occurred and take the appropriate actions. Of note is that I also set `e.Handled` to true so that the scroll viewer doesn't start scrolling while I move around the control.

And finally, we are ready to actually use this thing. I therefore have a scrollviewer with my touch and hold control:

```xml
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource MyScrollViewer}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeButtons}" x:Name="SomeButtonsRoot">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource SomeButtonsWrapPanel}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:SomeButton Icon="{Binding Icon}" Text="{Binding Name}"
                                     SelectCmd="{Binding ButtonSelectedCmd}" SelectCmdParam="{Binding SomeParam}"
                                     TouchedAndHeld="{Binding DataContext.SomeButtonDragStartedCmd, ElementName=SomeButtonsRoot}"
                                     ManipulationDeltaChanged="{Binding DataContext.SomeButtonDraggingCmd, ElementName=SomeButtonsRoot}">
                                     
                    <controls:SomeButton.TouchedAndHeldParam>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource List}">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="CanvasRoot"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </controls:SomeButton.TouchedAndHeldParam>
                    
                </controls:SomeButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The scrollviewer is placed inside a `Canvas`. Inside the same `Canvas` I then have another control:

```xml
<controls:SomeButton Icon="{Binding Icon}" Text="{Binding Name}" Panel.ZIndex="100"
                     Canvas.Left="{Binding InitialPosition.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding InitialPosition.Y}"
                     ManipulationDelta="{Binding Translation}"/>
```

This is the control that will actually be dragged around. The controls in the scroll viewer initiate the touch and hold dragging and then I pass all the manipulation data from the initiating control to this control. The reason I am not dragging the control that started the process, is because scroll viewer, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607368/wpf-animation-on-scrollviewer-children-clipped-by-scrollviewer) and other answers on stack overflow, will always clip to bounds. So, instead of messing with margins, paddings and Z indices, I just place a proxy control in the canvas that I can move wherever I want and I know it will be visible.

The code so far is promising. When I touch and hold the control in the scroll viewer, another control pops up righ above it and when I move my finger, that control perfectly reflects my gestures **but only on the Y axis**. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to see what the ScrollViewer is actually doing, so I searched for the source code. Fortunately, I found the code [right here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ScrollViewer.cs).

Starting with line 1645, inside the `OnManipulationStarting` override, the code checks what panning mode was set for the ScrollViewer and, based on the value, it changes the `ManipulationModes` of the `ManipulationStartingEventArgs`. For `PanningMode.VerticalOnly`, the mode is set to `ManipulationModes.TranslateY`. Aha! That's why I was only getting the Y values.

To fix this "feature", I simply extended the `ScrollViewer` class and overriden the same `OnManipulationStarting` and made sure that manipulation mode remains unchanged:

```cs
public class TouchScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnManipulationStarting(ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        var initialMode = e.Mode;       // Keep note of the original manipulation mode.
        base.OnManipulationStarting(e); // Let the ScrollViewer do it's thing.
        e.Mode = initialMode;           // Ensure the original manipulation mode is used.
    }
}
```

Thankfully, `OnManipulationStarting` is actually part of the `UIElement` class, which the `ScrollViewer` ultimately extends, and is marked as `protected`, so we can override it in our extension class as we see fit.

I switched to using `TouchScrollViewer` in XAML instead of the original `ScrollViewer`, and now everything works as expected.

I won't mark this as the definitive answer for now, just in case someone offers a better solution.

In case the link goes down or the code on the page changes, here are the relevant bits:

```cs
protected override void OnManipulationStarting(ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    PanningMode panningMode = PanningMode;
    if (panningMode != PanningMode.None)
    {
        ...
        
        if (ShouldManipulateScroll(e, viewport))
        {
            // Set Manipulation mode and container
            if (panningMode == PanningMode.HorizontalOnly)
            {
                e.Mode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
            }
            else if (panningMode == PanningMode.VerticalOnly)
            {
                e.Mode = ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Mode = ManipulationModes.Translate;
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```